# Is there any way to set polygon features fill color and outline programmatically?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap, symbology, feature-layer

By some process I am creating a polygon feature layer. Before adding the layer in the map, I want to set polygon's fill color to no color and set polygon's outline color and width. I am working with C#.

Is there a way to set polygon feature layer's fill color or outline in ArcObjects?

Comment: do you want to set up a UniqueValue renderer, i.e. different symbols for all polygons or the same symbol for all polygons?

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe: same symbol for all polygons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the renderer for your layer. Since you want to use the same symbology for all, you will have to use a [ISimpleRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000qs2000000)

Using an [IFillSymbol](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFillSymbol_Interface/001w0000015s000000/), you can set the border and the color for your polygons. Set this as the symbol for your ISimpleRenderer and set that as the FetureRenderer on your IFeatureLayer.

Also have a look at this article: [How to define a renderer for your layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000000t8000000.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
public void RenderLayer_color(IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer, IRgbColor pMamau)
        { 
            IGeoFeatureLayer pGeoFeatureLayer;
            pGeoFeatureLayer = (IGeoFeatureLayer)pFeatureLayer;
            IFeatureRenderer pFeatureRender;
            pFeatureRender = (IFeatureRenderer) new SimpleRenderer();                        
            IFillSymbol pFillSymbol;
            pFillSymbol = (IFillSymbol) new SimpleFillSymbol();            
            pFillSymbol.Color = pMamau;

            ISimpleRenderer pSimpleRenderer;
            pSimpleRenderer = new SimpleRenderer();            
            pSimpleRenderer.Symbol = (ISymbol) pFillSymbol;

            pGeoFeatureLayer.Renderer =  IFeatureRenderer)pSimpleRenderer;            
        }
```